Uploaded images only display after running pm2 restart all
I'm facing an issue with my Next.js application deployed on a server. When I upload an image, it doesn't display immediately. Instead, I have to run pm2 restart all to see the uploaded image on the frontend.
Setup:Next js 14 / ubuntu / nginx / pm2
When I upload an image, it successfully gets saved to the public folder, but the image is not accessible via the browser until I restart the application using the command pm2 restart all.
What I've tried:

Verified that the image is indeed saved in the correct folder
Checked file permissions for the public directory
Tried refreshing the cache and hard-reloading the page

when i run pm2 logs i got:

Question: How can I make the images available immediately after upload without restarting the application? Is there a way to refresh the Next.js cache or force it to recognize new files without a full restart?
Any help would be appreciated!
